# How do I use CGAffineTransformMakeScale and Rotation at once?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

```
((UIImageView*)[dsry objectAtIndex:0]).transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57*2);
((UIImageView*)[dsry objectAtIndex:0]).transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5,.5);
```

Just one of these works at a time. How can I save a transformation and then apply another?
Cheers

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To expand upon what Peter said, you would want to use code like the following:

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform;
newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57*2);
((UIImageView*)[dsry objectAtIndex:0]).transform = CGAffineTransformScale(newTransform,.5,.5);
```

The CGAffineTransformMake... functions create new transforms from scratch, where the others concatenate transforms.  Views and layers can only have one transform applied to them at a time, so this is how you create multiple scaling, rotation, and translation effects on a view at once.

You do need to be careful of the order in which transforms are concatenated in order to achieve the correct effect.

Answer (score 10):

From the Apple Documentation:

> CGAffineTransformConcat Returns an
>   affine transformation matrix
>   constructed by combining two existing
>   affine transforms.

```
CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformConcat (
   CGAffineTransform t1,
   CGAffineTransform t2
);
```

> Parameters t1 The first affine
>   transform.
>
> t2 The second affine transform. This
>   affine transform is concatenated to
>   the first affine transform.
>
> Return Value A new affine
>   transformation matrix. That is, t’ =
>   t1*t2.
>
> Discussion Concatenation combines two
>   affine transformation matrices by
>   multiplying them together. You might
>   perform several concatenations in
>   order to create a single affine
>   transform that contains the cumulative
>   effects of several transformations.
>
> Note that matrix operations are not
>   commutative—the order in which you
>   concatenate matrices is important.
>   That is, the result of multiplying
>   matrix t1 by matrix t2 does not
>   necessarily equal the result of
>   multiplying matrix t2 by matrix t1.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just took aout the CGAFfineTransform's and it works great!

Answer (score 2):

> Just one of these works at a time.

Right, because you replaced the first one with the second.

> How can I save a transformation and then apply another?

[Concatenate them together](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformConcat), and assign the resulting matrix to the property.

You can store a transformation matrix in a variable of type `CGAffineTransform`; you can use that for intermediate steps in more complex transformations, or to make the code clearer (or both).